# Retrieve facebook user info using php

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Actually I used javascript facebook sdk for retrieve user profile information. so I used following api call

```
FB.api(
    "/me",
    function (response) {
        if (response && !response.error) {
            /* handle the result */
        }
    }
);
```

so this work fine and I retrieved user details. but now I need to retrieve that logged user details using php. I used `php sdk 4.0`

```
require_once 'Facebook/FacebookSession.php';
require_once 'Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php';

use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('****','****');

$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper( 'http://localhost/' );
$session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();

if($session) {
try {

    $user_profile = (new FacebookRequest(
        $session, 'GET', '/me'
    ))->execute()->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());

    echo "Name: " . $user_profile->getName();

} catch(FacebookRequestException $e) {

    echo "Exception occured, code: " . $e->getCode();
    echo " with message: " . $e->getMessage();

}

}
```

but it wasn't work. here $session gave null value please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to API

```
/* make the API call */
$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'GET',
  '/me'
);
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
/* handle the result */
```

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user

Comment: so please tell me how I create that $session object

Answer (score 1):

You need to ask the user to login first, and then `$session` won't be null.

```
if ( $session ) {

  // your code here

} else {
  // show login url
  echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLoginUrl() . '">Login</a>';
}
```

If you already have a valid `access_token`, then you can create a new session using it:

```
$session = new FacebookSession( $access_token );
```

And then the rest of your code will work.